# Fotorama 4 disable arrow

Tags: javascript, fotorama

I need help with fotorama 4.
I want to disable the nav arrows

`data-arrow="false"
data-arrows="false"`
`$('#my-fotorama').fotorama({arrows: 'false'});
$('#my-fotorama').fotorama({arrows: 'null'});`
not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should download uncompressed version, and then, add few changes...

I have added one option:

```
 arrows: true // default option, could be false, too =>2636. line of code...
```

And, few small changes in setOptions function:

```
function setOptions () {
    o_fade = opts.transition === 'crossfade' || opts.transition === 'dissolve';

    o_loop = opts.loop && (size > 2 || o_fade);

    var classes = {add: [], remove: []};

    if (size > 1) {
      o_nav = opts.nav;
      o_navTop = opts.navPosition === 'top';
      classes.remove.push(selectClass);
if(opts.arrows) {
      $arrs.show();
}

else {
     $arrs.hide();
}
      arrsUpdate();
    } else {
      o_nav = false;

      $arrs.hide();
    }
```

now you can set arrows options (show/hide) directly in html, like this:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-arrows="false">
```

complete, updated code: http://pastebin.com/zg4yJCCb

Answer (score 1):

If you use the recent version (Fotorama 4.5.2 at the moment), there is now a built-in option for that:

**arrows** - true / false / 'always'

```
$(".fotorama").fotorama({ arrows: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I recommend a CSS approach:

```
.fotorama__arr {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Add this somewhere in your styles, not `fotorama.css`.

Also I do not recommend to change the `fotorama.js`. But, of course, you can do it if you don’t care about upgrades in the future.